# How to install HTML package for python3.7

Tags: html, python-3.x

I want to install HTML package for python3.7 but It's is giving error while installing

I tried command `pip install html` but getting errors in console

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'; 'html' is not a package
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-apo0cgnw\html\

Comment: `html` is already part of Standard Library that comes with Python 3.x
Why you want to install it?

Just directly use it by importing.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/html.html

Comment: I want to use `from html import HTML` so that I can directly use HTML inbuilt functions

Answer (score -1):

I am getting the same error: archlinux running a virtualenv.  I'm looking around it appears to be a problem with a file in there called 'six.py'.  Not sure what the problem is but it appears the project has been orphaned because it was consistently updated until 2011.  (Also not sure what all of this code is doing in there, similar libraries like 'vapory' are much smaller. - less bloat, less stuff to go wrong)  I would suggest either trying it on Python2.x (since it appears that's where it was developed), contacting the developer, or using a different package.

Answer (score -1):

1) download the `.tar.gz` file OR `.zip` file according to your OS from this 
[link](https://pypi.org/project/html/1.7/#files) .
 
2) After downloading , install that downloaded package by the following code : `pip install ./downloads/SomeProject-1.0.4.tar.gz` 


And then again follow the below step 

You can import the `html` package as shown below. `pip install` is not required, as `html` comes with the Standard library, post Python v3.x,

```
>>> from html import HTML
>>> h = HTML()
>>> h.p('Hello, world!')
>>> print h  # or print(h) in python 3+
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

See the [html 1.16 project description](https://pypi.org/project/html/) for more detail .

Comment: I tried same thing but Its errors as "cannot find reference 'HTML' in '__init__.py'

Comment: When I try `from html import HTML`. It is giving error as ImportError: cannot import name 'HTML' from 'html' (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\html\__init__.py)

Comment: Finally , try out this updated code . @VeereshHollur

Comment: I tried by downloading `.tar.gz` and `pip install C:\Users\username\Downloads\html-1.16.tar.gz` It is giving same error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'; 'html' is not a package Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-apo0cgnw\html\

Comment: It seems that the html package for python3 is nothing like the python2 html. They seem to be for very different purposes. Is there an easy replacement for the py2 html.HTML? If anyone knows of one please let me know.